# Trying to do Delta-Epsilon proof of a multivariable inverse tri-function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, polar-coordinates, epsilon-delta

I was given
$$\lim_{{(x, y) \to (0,0)}} \arctan(x - y)(x + y)$$
I noticed the limit is just zero.
$$\lim_{{(x, y) \to (0,0)}} \arctan(x - y)(x + y) = L = 0$$
I set up the proof
$$WTS:\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 \space s.t. if 0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta, then |\arctan(x - y)(x + y) - L| < \epsilon$$
So far I noticed a change in the coordinate system can be handy.
$$x=r\cos{\theta} \space \space y=r\sin{\theta}$$
$$\therefore 0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta \implies 0<\sqrt{r^2(\cos^2{\theta}+\sin^2{\theta})}<\delta \implies 0<|r|<\delta$$
and
$$|\arctan(x - y)(x + y) - L| < \epsilon \implies |\arctan{r^2(\cos^2{\theta}-\sin^2{\theta})}|< \epsilon$$
becomes
$$|\arctan{(r^2cos(2\theta))}| < \epsilon$$
But what should I do now? How do I find δ in terms of ϵ?(edit: fixed a tri identity mistake)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $\varepsilon>0$. Now, take $\delta>0$ such that $\delta<\min\left\{\frac\varepsilon2,\frac{\tan1}2\right\}$. Then, if $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$, both $|x|$ and $|y|$ are smaller than $\frac\varepsilon2$, and therefore $|x+y|\leqslant|x|+|y|<\varepsilon$. On the other hand, $|x-y|<\tan1$, and therefore $\left|\arctan(x-y)\right|<1$. So, $\left|\arctan(x-y)(x+y)\right|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Is it possible to elaborate a little bit about the choice of delta? How do you come up with these two numbers ε/2 and (tan1)/2? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I picked $\delta<\frac\varepsilon2$ so that\begin{align}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta&\iff\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\frac\varepsilon2\\&\implies|x|,|y|<\frac\varepsilon2\\&\implies|x+y|<\varepsilon.\end{align}And I picked $\delta<\frac{\tan1}2$ so that\begin{align}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta&\iff\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\frac{\tan1}2\\&\implies|x-y|<\tan1\\&\implies\bigl|\arctan(x-y)\bigr|<1.\end{align}

Comment: I realize the question was poorly constructed. The question can be interpreted in 2 ways (x+y)arctan(x−y) or arctan[(x−y)(x+y)]. Is there a way to do the latter one? I am sorry but the question I was given is actually very ambiguous. I cannot tell which one they want me to solve either.

Comment: In the case of $\arctan\bigl((x-y)(x+y)\bigr)=\arctan(x^2-y^2)$, take $\delta=\sqrt{\tan\varepsilon}$. Then\begin{align}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta&\iff x^2+y^2<\tan\varepsilon\\&\implies x^2-y^2<\tan\varepsilon\\&\implies\arctan\left(x^2-y^2\right)<\varepsilon.\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Rather than the Euclidean metric, I would use the taxicab metric.  If the proof is valid under the taxicab metric it will be valid under the euclidean metric.

$d((x,y),(0,0)) = |x| + |y|$

$|x+y| \le |x|+|y| = \delta$ and $|x-y| \le |x|+|y| =\delta$

For all $x,y$

$|\arctan (x-y)| < |x-y|$

$|(x+y) \arctan (x-y)| \le  \delta^2$

Set $\delta < \sqrt \epsilon$ to complete the proof.

Comment: I am not sure about whether the question is asking for (x+y)arctan(x−y) or arctan((x+y)(x−y)). It was not very clear when the question was given without proper parenthesis. Is there a way to answer to latter one, arctan((x+y)(x−y))?

Comment: $\arctan ((x+y)(x-y)) < (|x|+|y|)^2$ for all the same reasons.